# Python - функция нахождения файла в папке

Tags: python, файлы

К меня есть некоторя папка ("data_base", к примеру), в которой хранятся файлы с расширением .txt. Требуется написать функцию, которая будет проверять, есть ли в этой папке файл с названием, например, "python.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая функция идет из коробки

```
import os 

os.path.exists('data_base/python.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.isfile(path) - является ли путь файлом.

import os
os.path.isfile("C:/Python35/python.exe")
True

os.path.isfile("C:/Python35/python.txt")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
a = 'Путь к папке/data_base'
file_list = os.listdir()
for i in file_list:
    if i=='python.txt':
       print('Найден')
```